# Can't print data on same line in ruby, even with 'print'.What should be used?

Tags: ruby

I am practicing a project in ruby. I have to print the data in the following style:

```
   Doctor    Patient     Timing
   John K     Jerry    16:00 to 17:00
```

My code is :

```
puts 'Enter Doctor\'s Name'
  @doc_name1 = gets
  if @doc_name1 == @doc_name
    puts "Doctor \t Patient \t Timing"
    print "#{@doc_name}\t #{@patient_name}\t"
    printf('%.2f', @from)
    print ' to '
    printf('%.2f', @to_time)
    puts
  else
    puts 'No such doctor available'
  end
```

But it's output is as follows:

```
Doctor   Patient     Timing
Jim
     jerry
    16.00 to 17.00
```

The code is working fine if used separately in other file. 
What is wrong ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the bad output in pry. I get the two-line example output that you put at the top of your post. I get two lines of output even for very large 'Doctor' and 'Patient' names. Can you elaborate on things like your Ruby version, the way you run the code, your OS and your terminal type?

Comment: If the user enters `“Welby”`, `@doc_name1` will be set equal to `”Welby\n”`. Therefore, if `@doc_name1 == @doc_name1`, the latter end with a newline character, so anything printed after `print @doc_name1` begins on a new line. You want `@doc_name1 = gets.chomp`, which will strip off `”\n”`. That applies to  `@doc_name` As well, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) method to remove any new line characters.

```
@doc_name1 = gets.chomp
```

And somehow the @patient_name also has new line characters
You might want to chomp that as well

```
print "#{@doc_name}\t #{@patient_name.chomp}\t"
```

If you want to know what exactly your string consists of try the [inspect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) method.

```
@doc_name.inspect
#=> "\"Jim\\n\""
```